# Javascript: Wait for user interaction, and then resume where you left off?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

How to code for, wait for user interaction, and then resume where you left off?

Example:

1) Catch the current timestamp
2) Show a form. User will entering with your information
3) Resume the code(Catch the current timestamp and do a AJAX request)

Comment: Javascript is a single-threaded language. You'll have to explicitly release control to the browser, wait for the form to be completed and go on with a callback function once the form is submitted.

Comment: Are you trying to measure the time spent filling the form?